# Какой корень в слове ОПУШКА?

Tags: словообразование

Пожалуйста, помогите найти корень в слове ОПУШКА.
Спасибо.

Comment: Ваш вариант?

Comment: Опушка-опушкой-опушки.Что меняется, а что неизменно?

Comment: опушк/а (леса)
о/пуш/к/а (шубы)

Comment: А зачем изменять слово?

Comment: Чтобы найти основу и окончание, а подобрав родственные слова, увидим членение основы.Для ОПУШКИ ЛЕСА трудно найти  родственные, их нет, основа нечленима, ОПУШК-корень, ОПУШКА ШУБЫ - пушить, пушок, пух - основа членима, корень ПУШ.

Comment: Родственные слова для *опушки леса* - опушечка, опушечный.  
>С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. Толковый словарь русского языка
ОПУШКА, -и, род. мн. -шек, жен. Край леса. Домик на опушке.
| прил. опушечный, -ая, -ое.

Comment: Что и подтверждает корень опушк/опушеч в слове опушка (леса) на современном этапе.

Answer (score 6):

Lanka, Ваши варианты *(опушк/а (леса) о/пуш/к/а (шубы)* для современного языка правильны. Состав слова меняется в зависимости от значения слова. Хотя исторически  и основа слова *опушка (леса)* тоже членилась.

Comment: Тихонов в своем Школьном словообразовательном словаре приводит цепочку : пух - пуш/ить - о/пуш/ить. Слово о/пуш/к/а НЕ представлено (??) Чегой-то автор испугался)

Answer (score 2):

Корень -  пуш ( пух ),  опушка  шубы - в  прямом  значении,  опушка  леса  -  в  метафорическом.  Сейчас  это  уже  особо  не  замечается.

Comment: Все правильно. Что такое *опушка*?  
Словарь Академии Российской :  
>**Опушь** и **опУшка**, умал. опушечка...  
1) Ремешки изъ меха, каковыми обшиваются подолъ и концы рукавовъ у зимняго платья.  
2) Края леса или острова, где мелкия, низкия растутъ деревья и кусты.

Опушечка - корень **пуш**. Если мы по стародревней традиции продолжаем писать мягкий знак в глаголах после шипящих, то выделять корень **пуш** в (лесной) опушке или о**пуш**ечке - тоже не великий труд. Пусть дети знают, откуда слово пошло.

Comment: Лесная опушечка :
>М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Невинные
рассказы/ Развеселое житье (1857-1863)
Однако идешь это иной раз по
опушечке, и вдруг на тебя дурость
найдет…

Answer (score 1):

> опушк/а (леса) о/пуш/к/а (шубы)

Да, это современное членение.
Исторически это было одно слово с двумя близкими значениями. 
В лесу - опушка это край леса, его "пушок". 
Я не знаю, можно ли напрямую сводить этот "зеленый пух" к мелким елочкам-сосеночкам, растущим обычно на краю леса, но есть такое слово "опушить", в одном из значений - растрепать края. Оно-то уж точно является связующим между краем леса и краем одежды.